# DTD is prohibited in this XML document -- how to change permissions?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd, oracle-coherence

I am using a 3rd-party .NET component which requires an XML configuration file.
I'm am using this in an ASP.NET application.

I get an error when configure the XML with the following dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE prod-config SYSTEM "cache-config.dtd">
```

The error is as follows:

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited
>   in this XML document. To enable DTD
>   processing set the ProhibitDtd
>   property on XmlReaderSettings to false
>   and pass the settings into
>   XmlReader.Create method.

prod-config.dtd is sitting in the same directory as the XML config file.

**I don't have access to the component code** to modify XmlReaderSettings, ProhibitDtd etc.
Is there anotherway I can modify or tag the XML file to permit the DTD to be accessed?

(FYI, the component is Oracle Coherence .NET client)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify the DTD at all?  If nothing is actually using it, then it would be simplest to just omit the DTD declaration altogether.

[Ths page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/ias/htdocs/coherence.html) on Oracle's site suggests the component is only supported on .NET 1.1.  I think the behaviour of refusing DTDs by default changed between .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0.  If you are tryingt run with .NET 2.0, I suggest you try downgrading.  Installing 1.1 side-by-side *might* work but you may ned to hack the configuration to force it to use the desired runtime version.

Comment: This gives the error: Could not find schema information for the element 'cache-config'.

Comment: I think this behaviour changed between .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.  Could it be that this component is only supported in .NET 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this same error, and I changed the line to:

```
<!DOCTYPE prod-config "cache-config.dtd">
```

and fixed the error. No idea why that works, and I'll probably get more errors because of this.

Comment: and what do you know, it doesn't work again! XML and Microsoft = ugly mix. Why do we even need DTDs? What is even a DTD?